# How to check multiple items for nullity in an AND fashion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I was wondering if there's a Pythonic/hacky way to check for all (or none) items and dependencies in a set to be null.

Suppose I have a variable `foo` that is a dict, but can be nullable:

```py
foo: Optional[dict] = None
```

And I want to check that both foo is not None or one of its keys:

```py
if foo is not None and foo.get('bar') is not None:
   pass
```

Using AND, it will "short-circuit" before anything else, so I'm safe checking for other keys on a nullable item.

I was thinking about ways of doing that more neatly, like we can do with `any()` or `all()`.

I though about doing it in a list comprehension, but it would fail:

```py
if not all(item is not None for item in [foo, foo.get('bar'), foo.get('baz')]:
   # Value Error! :sad
```

One way could be using a try/catch, but that is ugly and won't make it look fun...

We can't go for walrus operator as it is not assignable in a list comprehension:

```py
if not all (item for item in [foo := foo or {}, foo.get('bar'), foo.get('baz')]:
   # SyntaxError, can't use walrus in list comprehension
```

I was also wondering if there's not a very well maintened tool that serves this purpose. Any better ideas?

Comment: Instead of `foo.get("bar") is not None`, I'd probably use `if "bar" not in foo`. In that case you can do something like `all(k in foo for k in ["bar", "baz"])`.

Comment: Your list comprehension fails because it has to build the entire list before `all` executes, but a generator might work.

Comment: Is short circuit a requirement or do you just want to safely test if any of a given list of keys in in the dictionary?

Comment: Are optional and dict module really useful / required? Are there any situation where we cant write a code without these modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply separate the `foo` from all the `foo.get`s and use an `and`:

```
if foo is not None and all(foo.get(key) is not None for key in ('bar', 'baz')):
```

You can also use `key in foo` to check if the key exists in the dictionary, this is actually safer because if the key exists and has a value of `None` in the dictionary, then using the above approach won't distinguish between the two cases:

```
if foo is not None and all(key in foo for key in ('bar', 'baz')):
```

Comment: Could also use set comparisons instead of the loop in your second approach: `if foo and foo.keys() >= {"bar", "baz"}:`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pattern matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#going-to-the-cloud-mappings):

```py
foo = {"bar": 111}


# foo can be None and it will work:
match foo:
    case {"bar": int(val)}:
        print(val)
```

Prints:

```
111
```

---

Or:

```py
foo = {"bar": 111}

match foo:
    case {"bar": val} if val is not None:
        print(val)
```

For multiple values:

```py
foo = {"bar": 111, "baz": "string"}

match foo:
    case {"bar": int(val1), "baz": str(val2)}:
        print(val1, val2)
```

Comment: How does the one for multiple values work with an arbitrary list of keys?

Comment: @DjaouadNM You can do `case {} if all(v is not None for v in foo.values()):`

Comment: This is a good solution, but it goes against the original idea of it being less verbose. It is indeed explicit and easy to follow, but the same amount of assignments/checks can be used to first assert that the dict is not empty, and then check the value.

Answer (score 1):

**Given:** *"I want to check that both foo is not None or one of its keys"*

I'm going to assume that you specifically want to check that a key has a non None value and that short circuiting is not a requirement.

I would start with leveraging `or` against our candidate dictionary to ensure that we can then call `get()`

Something like:

```py
sum((foo or {}).get(key) is not None for key in test_keys)
```

or maybe:

```py
any(map(lambda key: (foo or {}).get(key) is not None, test_keys))
```

I think either will return something you can use in an `if` statement:

```py
test_keys = ["bar", "bat"]

foo = None
if sum((foo or {}).get(key) is not None for key in test_keys):
    print(f"dictionary {foo} has a valid key")

foo = {"asf": True}
if sum((foo or {}).get(key) is not None for key in test_keys):
    print(f"dictionary {foo} has a valid key")

foo = {"bar": None}
if sum((foo or {}).get(key) is not None for key in test_keys):
    print(f"dictionary {foo} has a valid key")

foo = {"bar": 1}
if sum((foo or {}).get(key) is not None for key in test_keys):
    print(f"dictionary {foo} has a valid key")
```

Should give you a result of:

```
dictionary {'bar': 1} has a valid key
```

Note I assume here as well that you are looking for a kind of one liner and you don't want to do something that starts with `if foo and ...` otherwise this answer by [@djaouadnm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78143214/218663) is what I would do.